# Python if json record exists dont add duplicate

Tags: python, json

So basically I just want to check if the json record already exitst in the json file and if so I don't want to add it. Is it possible guys? I just can't figure it out. I hope somebody could help me. I would really appreciate it.

**main.py**

```
with io.open('data.json', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
for f in unique_following:
    data = {}
    data['insta'] = []
    data['insta'].append({  
    'id': f,
    'dm': False
    })
    json.dump(data,fp,indent=1)

with open('data.json') as fp:
for f in unique_following:
    recipients=f
    print(text,recipients)
    time.sleep(5)
```

**data.json**

```
{
 "insta": [
  {
   "id": 6864438512,
   "dm": false
  }
 ]
}{
 "insta": [
  {
   "id": 7467167660,
   "dm": false
  }
 ]
}
```

**So if that record writes to data.json**

```
{
 "insta": [
  {
   "id": 6864438512,
   "dm": false
  }
 ]
}
```

**I want this output**

```
{
 "insta": [
  {
   "id": 6864438512,
   "dm": false
  }
 ]
}{
 "insta": [
  {
   "id": 7467167660,
   "dm": false
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Are those JSONs valid?

Comment: Well python can work with them

Comment: No, `data.json` isn't JSON, and Python's `json` module won't read it. Similarly, `I want this output` isn't JSON, and Python's `json` module won't produce it.

Comment: python read it: https://gyazo.com/3d42a56c8cb18941c7cbe7769fa6145b
and writes it to data.json: https://gyazo.com/b97a3655fc517cd2b72545479f7f3fee

Comment: you're definitely missing commas to separate each `insta` objects

Comment: I couldn't see what your `try.py` was, so I wrote my own that attempts to parse `data.json`. Here is my `try.py` along with its error message:  https://ideone.com/yINIXp  `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 9 column 2 (char 63)`

Comment: So it means thats not a valid json? my bad. I try to fix the json file then.
Is this a valid json? https://pastebin.com/kNeU8SNt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rethink how you construct and how you access `data.json`. Simply joining together multiple valid JSON strings does not produce one larger valid JSON string. In fact, the result is not valid at all.

If it were me, I'd use a database of some kind. Failing that, if the number of items is small enough, I'd put all of the data in a list, then update the list with each new item. Maybe like this:

```
with open('data.json') as fp:
    list_of_data = json.load(fp)

dirty = False
for f in unique_following:
    if not any(data['insta']['id'] == f for data in list_of_data):
        data['insta'] = [{'id': f, 'dm': False}]
        dirty = True
if dirty:
    with open('data.json', 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(fp, list_of_data, indent=1)
```

From your comments, your new data structure is a `dict` with one key: `insta`. The value of `insta` is a `list` of `dict`s.

Perhaps this program will help:

```
import json

# New data to add to the file
unique_following = ['7', '8', '9', '7']

# Read in existing file
with open('data.json') as fp:
    list_of_data = json.load(fp)

dirty = False
for f in unique_following:
    if not any(data['id'] == f for data in list_of_data['insta']):
        list_of_data['insta'].append({'id': f, 'dm': False})
        dirty = True
if dirty:
    # Write the file with new data
    with open('data.json', 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(list_of_data, fp, indent=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for the snippet! Finally I created a valid json file (I guess):
https://pastebin.com/7t33Eu77
But when your snippet read it I got this error:
https://pastebin.com/uAZdGVx6